# Is this checksum in documentation wrong or am I not seeing something?

Tags: python, checksum

I'm working on interfacing with a certain chip accepting commands via serial, ending with a checksum calculated by XORing all the characters "between $ and * preceding the checksum.

The code I use to calculate the checksum is:

```
    def checksum(cmd):
        chk = 0
        if type(cmd) is str:
            cmd = cmd.encode("latin_1")

        for i in range(len(cmd)):
            chk = chk ^ cmd[i]

        res = hex(chk)[2:].upper()
        res = res if len(res) > 1 else f"0{res}"
        return res
```

This works in the vast majority of cases except for the example on top of page 168 of the [documentation of the chip](https://www.u-blox.com/en/docs/UBX-13003221).

The example figures the checksum is 3C while for me running the above function returns 5D.

```
>>> checksum("PUBX,04,073731.00,091202,113851.00,1196,15D,1930035,-2660.664,43,")
5D
```

Is this a documentation error or is my code wrong?

Comment: `5D` is the correct checksum - verified by pasting the packet into uBlox's u-center software as a custom NMEA message, and seeing how it filled in the checksum field.  I checked a couple of the other examples from that document, and they had correct checksums - no idea how this one happened to be wrong.